# Shortcut related to macro working outside Excel

Tags: excel, vba, keyboard-shortcuts

I have one question, let´s supposed I work on several workbooks in Excel and I minimize them all to work on other applications outside Excel...

Then I want to come back to the last workbook in Excel I minimized, could we create a macro which works outside Excel via a shortcut (for example clt+E) which allows us to do that?

Through internet I found this macro (please see VBA code below) but it works only if I am already inside Excel (I tried to allocate a shortcut Clt+E). Indeed it does not work outside Excel, I mean if all my Excel Windows are minimized at the Level of my taskbar Windows, the shortcut will not work.

If someone knows the solution by chance, it would be really fantastic.

```
Sub OpenWorkbook_78()
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized 'maximize Excel
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized 'maximize the workbook in Excel
End Sub
```

Comment: Would alt+tab work for you here?

Comment: Thanks a lot Oxwilder.